# Pattern matching and arity in Haskell

Tags: haskell

While trying to define a Haskell function which corresponds to repeated evaluation, I ran into an "Equations give different arities" error. This is my code:

```
nEvals :: Int -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
nEvals 1   = ($) --equivalent to nEvals 1 f x = f x
nEvals k f = (nEvals (k - 1) f) . f --equivalent to nEvals k f x = nEvals (k - 1) f (f x)
```

I don't quite understand why Haskell is giving this error, since I'm using pattern matching, not explicitly assigning a value for a given set of inputs. Perhaps Haskell only allows pattern matching on a fixed number of parameters? If so, could someone explain why that decision was made?

Comment: You can skip pattern matching and think of this as a fold: make a list of `k` functions using `replicate`, then combine them into a single function using `foldr (.) id`.

Comment: I believe this question is a duplicate, hence I closed it. If you disagree, and think that your question is more nuanced, feel free to explain why so that we can vote to reopen.

Comment: @chepner, ohhh great idea! Didn't think of that, thank you!

Comment: @chi, I'm sorry, that's the same as what I meant to ask, I must've missed that question.

Comment: @PrimeNumbers No problem at all :) . Mine wasn't a complaint -- I just wanted to be sure I did not close this too hastily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Haskell Report [section 4.4.3.1](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#sect4.4.3.1) requires it:

> A function binding binds a variable to a function value. The general form of a function binding for variable x is:
>
> ```
> x p11 … p1k  match1
> …
> x pn1 … pnk  matchn
> ```
>
> where each pij is a pattern, [...]
>
> Note that all clauses defining a function must be contiguous, and **the number of patterns in each clause must be the same**.

It doesn't explicitly say why, but it does state that:

> Translation: The general binding form for functions is semantically equivalent to the equation (i.e. simple pattern binding):
>
> ```
> x = \ x1 … xk -> case (x1, …, xk) of
>  (p11, …, p1k) match1
>  …
>  (pn1, …, pnk) matchn
> ```

This translation would not be possible with different numbers of patterns.

It might have been possible to instead define the behavior in terms of e.g.

```
case (x11, …, x1k) of
  (p11, …, p1k) match1
  _ -> case (x21, …, x2k) of
         (p21, …, p2k) match2
         _ ->  ...
```

but it seems like a mess that it's harder for the compiler to work efficiently with, for very little benefit.

Answer (score 4):

You should specify the same number of parameters in all the clauses of the definition of your function. This thus means that you implement this as:

```
nEvals :: Int -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
nEvals 1 f = f  -- added f as parameter
nEvals k f = (nEvals (k - 1) f) . f
```

we can also reduce the number of parameters with:

```
nEvals :: Int -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
nEvals 1 = id
nEvals k = (.) =<< nEvals (k - 1)
```

Comment: I avoided the first implementation because I wanted to try to minimize the number parameters as that's aesthetically nicer to me. I'm just learning Haskell, so I wasn't familiar with the "=<<" function in the second implementation, thank you!